# Finish vinyl plank flooring (subfloor step)

Tags: flooring

Just wondering the proper way to finish this project:

[image]

Comment: what you need is shag carpet. :)

Comment: Any updates? Curious how you solved this.

Comment: I cut a piece of the vinyl flooring to the size. Brad nailed it on. Actually worked great and looked decent (you wouldn't notice it unless you were looking for it).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something you should have thought about before placing the new flooring :)

However you should probably put a door sill in.
As for material there are various options usually stone, wood or metal.
You'll have to choose what best suits your home.
If you want the drop to be gradual you should get an angled sill.
Most likely you will end up having to cut into the newly laid floor a bit to accommodate for the door sill.

Comment: Well, the subfloor was there when we moved it. We just ripped out the carpet and threw on some vinyl. I was more thinking finishing it with a stair nose piece. Also, it's just vinyl, so taking some off would be a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

Finish end at step problem. 
You said, " I was more thinking finishing it with a stair nose piece."

Yes, I do it that way. They come 2" x2 with screws to install and will hold up to traffic. Also...

There are rubbery vinyl edge products that come 4 inches deep, and with a lip down. This will look more professional. Black or brown colors. Glue made for it holds it permanently in place. Both styles come large and need cut to fit. Hope this helps.